# Not able to login into coursera using mechanize

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I wrote this Python script for signing in into Coursera so that I could download all the lecture videos from one of the courses I am enrolled in. But when I run the script I get this error

```
mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching nr 0
```

Here is the code of my script:

```
import mechanize

br=mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open('https://class.coursera.org/inforisk-004/auth/auth_redirector?type=login&subtype=normal&email=')
br.select_form(nr=0) 
br.form["email"] = 'myemail'
br.form["password"] = 'mypassword'
br.submit()
```

Instead of

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

I also tried

```
br.select_form(predicate=lambda f: 'class' in f.attrs and 
               f.attrs['class'] == 'coursera-signin-form')
```

but then I get the error

```
mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching predicate <function <lambda> at 0x1b29758>
```

Comment: That form doesn't exist in the returned HTML. It's constructed with JavaScript.

Comment: So does means I cannot use `mechanize` to login into Coursera?

Comment: @Archit Verma You can login in browser, explore the cookies (with Firebug or Dev tools) and put them into your script. In this case, you don't have to login

Comment: @ArchitVerma: You'd have to send the right POST request to do it,

Comment: @Blender Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ArchitVerma: Look at what request is sent when you try to log in. Your browser's web development tools have a tab for this.

Comment: @Blender https://github.com/KartikTalwar/Coursera This uses `mechanize` to login into Coursera

Comment: @ArchitVerma: It's a year old. Coursera changed.